# Get children models not passing through database in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

Having these two models:

```
class Campaign(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

class AdGroup(models.Mode):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, related_name='ad_groups', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

There is a way to access to the campaign children without create the row in the db?

```
c = Campaign()
a1 = AdGroup(campaign=c)
a2 = AdGroup(campaign=c)

for ad_group in c.ad_groups:
    do_something()
```

Comment: No, since Django's relations are not "signalled" about the update.

Comment: You can look at [django-modelcluster](https://github.com/wagtail/django-modelcluster) which allows you to do that.